# PHP | Запрос по типу Callback API к php скрипту

Tags: php, запрос

Как сделать вот такой запрос от одного php скрипта к другому на моём хостинге?

```
{"date":1541194003,"from_id":458252432,"text":"awd"}
```

Comment: А в чем у вас проблема? Передаете массив данных (в данном случае обернутый в json) POST-запрос на нужный url и принимаете его.

Comment: используте curl

Comment: и с помощью какой функции этот массив данных (в данном случае обёрнутый в json) передать?

Comment: ещё раз - используйте curl

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте curl. [Пример](https://joshtronic.com/2014/08/17/how-to-execute-an-http-post-using-php-curl/)

```
// Sets our destination URL
$endpoint_url = 'https://somesite.com/path/to/endpoint';

// Creates our data array that we want to post to the endpoint
$data_to_post = [
    'field1' => 'foo',
    'field2' => 'bar',
    'field3' => 'spam',
    'field4' => 'eggs',
];

// Sets our options array so we can assign them all at once
$options = [
    CURLOPT_URL        => $endpoint_url,
    CURLOPT_POST       => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_to_post, //json_encode($data_to_post)
];



// Initiates the cURL object
$curl = curl_init();

// Assigns our options
curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);

// Executes the cURL POST
$results = curl_exec($curl);

// Be kind, tidy up!
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: У автора вопроса данные приходят в json, можете обернуть `json_encode($data_to_post)`